# How to add group Button or some Button to RecyclerView after click on item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I just want to custom `RecyclerView`, and I just want to know is it possible to change display button after click on item.

[image: 7HbX.png]

Comment: You can use a click listener which changes the visible items. You may be interested to look at `ViewAnimator` and the likes.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late to the party, but it might help someone. In your

> onBindViewHolder

of the Adapter class, get the position of that particular element and register a click listener. Then do the changes you would like.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position){
//all your views binding code
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick(View v){
//reference your item attributes and manipulate them as you wish
}
});
}
```